# Skype BotFramework answer calls automatically

Tags: botframework, skype, skype-bots

I am using Node.js to create Skype bots. I want my bot to answer calls automatically from selected contacts and create a group voice chat consisting of bot, caller, and me. I couldn't understand the documentation much. Is there a way to do it? If yes, can you give me a brief example?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots are not supported in group calls right now because of privacy reasons.

Group calling for media bots has been disabled because the Skype clients do not have currently have the appropriate privacy controls in place to inform the participants that a bot can hear and/or see them.

There is no timeframe available regarding when calling/real-time media bots will be supported in group calls. For now, calling and real-time media bots are allowed only in 1-to-1 Skype calls.

Comment: Can a bot redirect an incoming call to another person as a 1-1 call?

Comment: you could route it through an IVR bot like in this example https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleIVRBot